# How to change application name in NativeScript

Tags: android, xml, telerik, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm working with **NativeScript** from **Telerik** and I made an app with a debug name ("notiApp") but now I can't change the app's name in launcher and action bar.

I already tried configuring my `AndroidManifest.xml` in `/app/App_Resources/Android/` modifying the `android:label` attribute of my `<application>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
    <application
        android:label="DESIRED NAME">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Also, I tried changing my project's root directory name for the new app desired name.

There's anything else I can do or any additional information I could provide?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Go into app >> App_Resources >> Android >> values folder.

There should be a strings.xml file - if not create it.

The content should be

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">DISPLAY APP NAME</string>
    <string name="title_activity_kimera">APK NAME</string>
</resources>`

p.s. these stackoverflow content check error messages are annoying!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't find that strings.xml in values folder that is referenced in the documentation. I didn't knew I could just create it!

p.s. Yes, they are pretty annoying xD

Comment: I have changed the app name and display name but my changes are not reflected

Comment: Also make sure to update the app name in this file, if needed: `App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values-v21/strings.xml`.  Note that styles applied in the values-v21 folder will be applied only to devices with API 21+.

Answer (score 20):

For the Angular flavor of NativeScript:

**Android app name:**

`App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`.  Create it if it does not exist.  Content is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">DISPLAY APP NAME</string>
  <string name="title_activity_kimera">APK NAME</string>
</resources>
```

**iOS App Name**

In `/Users/ryan/projects/snaptab-mobile-app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist` replace the `<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>` value of `CFBundleDisplayName` with your app name.  Ex: `<string>My NS APP</string>`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've submitted PR to update docs https://github.com/NativeScript/docs/pull/1512 @gonzalo-diaz-ailan can you please mark this as correct? current one is incorrect.

Comment: @rynop The selected answer works fine for me. This answer does not as I have no src folder under Android. I am using Nativescript-Vue if that makes any difference.

Comment: what is `title_activity_kimera` and how it differs from `app_name`?

Comment: @Jason yea sorry my ans is for Angular only. I don't know how to use the other flavors.

Comment: But would it more accurate to update the `${PRODUCT_NAME}` variable where is that coming from how to update this variable instead of hardcode the name?

Answer (score 12):

this worked for me:

**For Android**

create App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MyAppName</string>
    <string name="title_activity_kimera">MyAppName</string>
</resources>
```

https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/publishing-android-apps#app-name

**For IOS**

The value is stored in the app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist file as the CFBundleDisplayName key. just changed to your custom app name
https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/publishing-ios-apps#app-name